# php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy production site

Tags: magento2, language, static-content

Currently in Stores > All Stores I have one store view (Dutch).

When I do command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` it generates files for `en_US`. I know with the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL` it's generating files for nl_NL.

But what is the advantage or purpose of this? Why do I have to do this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

To be short in production mode you'll have to use `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL` for example if you have installed theme with localization files. If you use this command without localization parameter - your static resources will be missing partially on your site if your system language is Dutch.

Here is what magento docs says:

> Static view files deployment is affected by Magento modes as follows:
>
> Developer mode: Magento generates them on demand, but the rest are
>   cached in a file for speed of access. Default and production modes:
>   Static files are not generated or cached.
>
> You must write static view files to the Magento file system manually
>   using the command discussed in this topic; after that, you can
>   restrict permissions to limit your vulnerabilities and to prevent
>   accidental or malicious overwriting of files.
>   You must write static view files to the Magento file system manually
>   using the command discussed in this topic; after that, you can
>   restrict permissions to limit your vulnerabilities and to prevent
>   accidental or malicious overwriting of files.

See "Overview"
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Try to enable production mode `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` and research how site deployment works.

Comment: ok thanks. Can you give an example of _- theme with localization files -_ What files, kind of files exactly do you mean?

Comment: I don't know such a free theme. But have a look at /magento-catalog/i18n/en_us.csv. Copy it and rename it by your localization code and implement into your module or theme, then translate it and run static deployment command. See for more details http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html